# Accommodation search engine that allows setting an approximate price range without a date?

Tags: budget, online-resources, accommodation, accommodation-search-engines

While looking for accommodation for my vacation, I have become rather frustrated with sites like [booking.com](http://www.booking.com/) where you have to set the check-in and check-out dates before you see any prices. Unfortunately I am at a (probably not unique) position where my schedule and destination preference are not by any means tight, but my budget *is*.

Are there any accommodation search engines that allow you to set a destination and an approximate price range without an exact date?

EDIT:

Let's rephrase this question in another way:

Is there a site that would show a *"From X Euro/$ per night"*-style price tag when supplied with an area and a date-range? Normally *From*-style price tags are a major problem, but in this case they could help a traveller weed out places that are too expensive and track down potentially good deals.

Comment: It's seasonal pricing that will make this difficult both for implementing the search engine and for designing an easy-to-use interface. But I agree it's a problem that needs solving!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Airbnb](http://www.airbnb.com) lets you do this. Not your average hotel search engine like [booking.com](http://www.booking.com/) but plenty of options there.

Comment: On different languages :) Cool.

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for, but interesting nonetheless... +1

Answer (score 6):

**Developer view**

Unfortunately, I think there is no such sites in a world. Maybe independent hotel sites, but not the search engines.

I worked with many of them, and only some of them had method to get the general information about prices, but even it this cases you were ought to set the start and end date for your trip.

This is because such queries are not very-informative and popular - prices are highly depends on room type, quantities of adults, children and infants, and date time period in which the trip is made.

Comment: Number of people and room types are definitely reasonable. Dates, however, are a bit of a problem, because if you care about the price you get into and endless hit & miss loop. By the time you do that you have wasted a lot of time, possibly for nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Google Maps shows average price of many hotels in search result. Also the recently released [Google Hotel Finder](http://www.google.com/hotelfinder/) (with experiment/beta badge) helps a lot to specify price range and searching area. I think it is one of the best tools publicly available out there.